# Scala, ZIO - convert Future[Either[...]] into ZIO

Tags: scala, future, zio

I have a simple method which returns `Future[Either[Throwable, MyValue]]`.
Now I would like to convert it to ZIO. I created:

```
def zioMethod(): ZIO[Any, Throwable, MyValue] =
    ZIO.fromFuture {implicit ec =>
       futureEitherMethod().flatMap { result => 
            Future(result)
       }
    }
```

But it didn't work without trace: `No implicit found for parameter trace: Trace`.

So, after I added `Trace` as implicit it still doesn't work correctly.
Is any other way to convert `Future[Either[,]]` into `ZIO`? Docs are not clear in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The signature (in the code or in the scaladoc) seems to be rather clear on this topic:

`ZIO.fromFuture[A]` converts a `Future[A]` into a `ZIO[Any, Throwable, A]`.

You pass in a `Future[Either[Throwable, MyValue]]`, so it would return a `ZIO[Any, Throwable, Either[Throwable, MyValue]]` - not a `ZIO[Any, Throwable, MyValue]` as your code expects.

To transfer the `Left` case of your `Either` onto the "error channel" of the `ZIO`, you have several options, e.g.:

Convert `Future[Either[Throwable, MyValue]]` to `Future[MyValue]` and then to ZIO:

```
def zioMethod(): ZIO[Any, Throwable, MyValue] =
  ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec =>
    futureEitherMethod().flatMap { 
      case Right(myValue)  => Future.successful(myValue)
      case Left(throwable) => Future.failed(throwable)
    }
  }
```

Convert to `ZIO[Any, Throwable, Either[Throwable, MyValue]]` and then to `ZIO[Any, Throwable, MyValue]`:

```
def zioMethod(): ZIO[Any, Throwable, MyValue] = {
  val fromFuture: ZIO[Any, Throwable, Either[Throwable, MyValue]] =
    ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec =>
      futureEitherMethod()
    }
  fromFuture.flatMap(ZIO.fromEither)
}
```

BTW: for me, this compiles without bringing any additional implicits in code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dRefNpH0SEO5aIjegV8RKw

**Update: alternative (more idiomatic?) solution**
As pointed out in the comments by @LMeyer, there's also `ZIO.absolve` and to me, that seems to be the more ZIO-idiomatic way (I have close to zero experience with ZIO myself):

```
ZIO.fromFuture { implicit ec =>
  futureEitherMethod()
}.absolve
```

Comment: I would just do `ZIO.fromFuture(_ => futureEitherMethod()).absolve`

Comment: Thanks! I hope you don't mind that I updated my post. That seems like the more idiomatic way to do it.